# Autocomplete minlength and maxheight is not working in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i entered the value in the text field it list the data from the database but i cannot able to fix the height and width of the list box. I given

```
minLength: 0,
 maxItem: 5,
```

but it is not affected.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#txtMedicineName").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                maxItem: 5,
                order: "asc",
                hint: true,
                accent: true,
                searchOnFocus: true,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete")',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return item;
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#txtMedicineName").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1,
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

[image: List]

[image: Big]

For Example: i click `crocin` from the list box i cannot able to fetch the corresponding id from the database.

[image: value]

How to get the crocin product id value from the database to text box.

[image: ...]

Comment: Your question is not clear at one point it is `i cannot able to fix the height and width of the list box` and at another point it is `i cannot able to fetch the corresponding id from the database.`.Please clarify your problem

Comment: when i search the MedicineName from the MedicineName textbox value listed from the database it's working fine but fro example search c listied all values like c but my require only five values related c value from the datavse display after scroll option only @brk

Comment: see my picture @brk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use slice which will limit your list to display

```
 response($.map(data.slice(0, 5), function (item)
                            {
                            return item.Value;
                        }))
```

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<input id="txtMedicineName" type="text" />



 <script>
        $(function ()
        {

        $("#txtMedicineName").on('focus', function () { $(this).keydown(); });

            $("#txtMedicineName").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                maxItem: 5,
                order: "asc",
                hint: true,
                accent: true,
                searchOnFocus: true,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete")',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.slice(0, 5), function (item)
                                {
                                return item;
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#txtMedicineName").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Add Style will show scroll

```
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    /* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
     * we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
     */
    * html .ui-autocomplete {
        height: 100px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: in your code working fine first 5 value listed remaining value is not listed.my required first five value list after value scroll down

Comment: You want to display scroll to list it will work for you i have update css have a look on it

Comment: .on('focus', function() { $(this).keydown(); }) how to use in this code

Comment: $("#txtMedicineName").on('focus', function () { $(this).keydown(); });

Comment: you just need to do key down as some one moves to autocomplete right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159669/discussion-between-saineshwar-and-ivin-raj).